# Portal user runs report and columns are missing

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type

I have a portal user set up who I allow to run custom report type.  Sometimes the report is missing columns that I see when I run the same report.  In field level security the portal user has access to those fields that make up the missing columns.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce support stated the portal user does not have access to any report columns related to "Partner" fields.  Consequently, those partner fields were left off the report.